# C# File System Watcher and FIleStream Writer

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created a FileSystem watcher and have registered 2 events. One is for creation and other for change.

```
FileSystemWatcher fswInbound = new FileSystemWatcher();
fswInbound.Path = "path to directory";
fswInbound.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
fswInbound.InternalBufferSize = 12288;
fswInbound.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(program.FileSystemWatcher_Created);
fswInbound.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(program.FileSystemWatcher_Created);
```

Than in same program I am creating files dynamically and trying to write into folder where FileSystem Watcher is listening.

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
      outfile.Write("Some really long string");
}
```

After a  new file is created. 2 events are getting fired. One is for change and other for creation. I only want the event of file creation to trigger. How can I avoid File Change event when I am creating file for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is by design according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged.aspx) To work around it I would have a common event handler which it looks like you have, Then I would check the the [FileSystemEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs.aspx) to check the [ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xf43e0.aspx) for file Creation or Change.

From above link:

> The OnCreated event is raised as soon as a file is created. If a file is being copied or transferred into a watched directory, the OnCreated event will be raised immediately, followed by one or more OnChanged events.